# Ruby's && operator

Tags: ruby, iterator, conditional-statements

In PHP, this evaluates to `true`:

```
$a = 1
$b = 2

var_dump($a && $b); // true
```

In ruby, this evaluates to `2`:

```
a = 1
b = 2
p a && b # 2
```

Why does ruby return the value of the last statement (when the first is true and the second one is also true) and does not return a boolean?

I have two arrays and I iterate them with an external iterator:

```
a = [1,2,3].to_enum
b = [5,6,7].to_enum
c = []

begin
  while a_next = a.next && b_next = b.next
    result = a_next + b_next
    p "a[x] + b[x] = c[x] = #{a_next} + #{b_next} = #{result}"
    c << result
  end
rescue 
  p c
end
```

The condition: `while a_next = a.next && b_next = b.next` sets `a_next = b_next` (the first question seems related to this behavior, I think).
But when I wrap the two `&&` operands, it works as expected: `(a_next = a.next) && (b_next = b.next)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's several aspects here.

> Why does ruby returns the value of the last statement (when the first is true and the second one is also true) and does not return a boolean?

Because it is more useful this way. This semantics is in fact so useful that PHP 7 added it (but as a new operator, `??`). In Ruby, just as in PHP, all values are truthy or falsy. Unlike PHP, Ruby has a much stricter idea about it: only `false` and `nil` are falsy, everything else is truthy. This allows you to easily give defaults:

```
name = options[:name] || "John Doe"
```

If `options[:name]` is not found and returns `nil`, then that part is falsy and the right side of `||` will be returned; otherwise, `options[:name]` will be returned.

In most cases you don't *need* a boolean, because truthiness or falsiness suffices. If you really really want to have a boolean, for example in order not to leak private information out of a class, the idiom `!!value` is common:

```
def has_name?
  !!(self.name || self.nickname)
end
```

The result of `!` (negation) is always boolean; if you negate twice, you will convert truthiness to `true` and falsiness to `false`.

Finally,

> The thing that bugs me is the condition in the `while` - `while a_next = a.next && b_next = b.next` - written like this, it always sets `a_next = b_next` (the first question seems related to this behavior, I think). But when i wrap the two `&&` operands - it works as expected - `(a_next = a.next) && (b_next = b.next) # works ok`.

Then you need to wrap them. That's due to operator precedence, and works like this by design, because it is more normal to write

```
blue_green = colour == :blue || colour == :green
```

than

```
blue_green = (colour == :blue || colour == :green)
```

There is another set of boolean operators that are actually designed to work like you propose, the only difference being the precedence, so you could write this and have it work:

```
while a_next = a.next and b_next = b.next
```

It is identical to

```
while (a_next = a.next) && (b_next = b.next)
```

A warning though: using `and` and `or` operators instead of `&&` and `||` improperly is a common enough mistake that many style guides outright ban them (they are useful *only* in this context - assignment inside loop conditions - and it can be solved with parentheses instead). [E.g.](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or):

> The `and` and `or` keywords are banned. It's just not worth it. Always use `&&` and `||` instead.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation! It really helped me clear some things out in my head. :)

Answer (score 6):

**Truthy and Falsy versus `true` and `false`**

Consider

```
    3 && 4     #=> 4 
    3 && false #=> false 
  nil && 4     #=> nil 
false && nil   #=> false 

    3 || 4     #=> 3 
    3 || false #=> 3 
  nil || 4     #=> 4 
false || nil   #=> nil
```

Recall that in Ruby, `false` and `nil` evaluate as logically `false` ("falsy"), and everything else evaluates as logically `true` ("truthy"). Therefore, there's generally no need to convert a falsy value to `false` or a `truthy` value to `true`. We could write, for example,

```
3 ? "happy" : "sad"
  #=> "happy"
nil ? "happy" : "sad"
  #=> "sad"
```

**Converting Truthy and Falsy to `true` and `false`**

If you insist, you can convert `truthy` and `falsey` values to `true` and `false` with the double-exclamation trick:

```
!!3 => !(!3) => !(false) => true
!!nil => !(!nil) => !(true) => false
```

**Tricks of the trade with `&&` and `||`**

It's often very handy to have `&&` and `||` defined the way they are. For example, if `h` is a hash, suppose we write

```
h[k] = (h[k] || []) << 3
```

If `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k] #=> nil`, so the expression reduces to

```
h[k] = [] << 3
  #=> [3]
```

Another example is summing elements of an array `arr` that are integers or `nil`:

```
arr.reduce(0) { |t,n| t + (n || 0) }
```

There are many other inventive ways you can make use of those two operators in Ruby that would not be possible if they just returned `true` or `false`.

**Code snippet**

Now let's turn to the code snippet you mentioned.

Firstly, your rescue clause is a bit distracting and `while`'s argument is always true and therefore a bit artificial, so let's write what you have as follows.

```
a = [1,2,3].to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each> 
b = [5,6,7].to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [5, 6, 7]:each> 
c = []
loop do
  a_next = a.next
  b_next = b.next
  result = a_next + b_next
  p "a[x] + b[x] = c[x] = #{a_next} + #{b_next} = #{result}"
  c << result
end
  # "a[x] + b[x] = c[x] = 1 + 5 = 6"
  # "a[x] + b[x] = c[x] = 2 + 6 = 8"
  # "a[x] + b[x] = c[x] = 3 + 7 = 10"
p c
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

When `a.next` is executed after all elements of `a` have been enumerated it will raise a `StopIteration` exception (see [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next)). The reason I chose [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) over `while` is that the former handles `StopIteration` exceptions by breaking out of the loop. Hence, no rescue is required. (btw, if you do rescue with `while`, you'd want `rescue StopIteration`, rather than rescuing all exceptions.)

Comment: Excellent explanation, Cary! Thank you for the examples - clean and conscious. They helped me better understand the possibilities of not just returning true/false. I pretty much got used to it and I do like it! Thanks again :)