# What does this logical AND operator do?

Tags: ruby, idioms, control-flow

In /rails/lib/rails.rb there is an idiom with the logical `&&` operator:

```
def root
  application && application.config.root
end
```

What is the meaning of this idiom? It seems to do some control flow, to only return application.config.root if application exists or something like that?

Comment: *"only return application.config.root if application exists"* - exactly that, yes. It returns `application` if it's `nil`, otherwise `application.config.root`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40925038/3001761.

Comment: wonderful. thanks. so the basic concept is that its a kind of control structure, right?

Comment: `X && Y` evaluates `X`. If `X` is neither `nil` nor `false`, this X is the value of the expression. Otherwise `Y` is the value of the expression. It's a concept you find in most programming languages. What programming language did you grow up with?

Comment: The idiom is called short-circuiting of logical expressions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation combined with the ruby idiom of returning the last expression evaluated. 
The following is meant with the expression that the logical operators in ruby are "lazy."

If the first argument of the boolean &&` junctor evaluates to false, the second expression isn't even evaluated anymore. False is returned.

true && true => true
true && false => false
false && true => false
false && false => false

true && 123 => 123

The opposite holds for the `or` operator.

Answer (score 4):

In ruby, logical operators are "lazy".

Consider the following:

```
def one
  puts "Called method one"
  false
end

def two
  puts "Called method two"
  true
end

puts "Calling one, then two:"
one && two

puts
puts "Calling two, then one:"
two && one
```

It gives this output:

```
Calling one, then two:
Called method one

Calling two, then one:
Called method two
Called method one
```

See what happened? When it called `one` and got `false`, it **didn't even bother** calling method `two` -- because it already knew that the final result would be `false`. (`false && false` == `false && true` == `false`.)

Now let's look back at the original code you posted:

```
def root
  application && application.config.root
end
```

What happens if `application == nil`? This code **doesn't even bother** evaluating the right hand side. Since `nil && literally_anything == nil`.

In other words, this is a safe-guard. It prevents the code from failing if `application == nil`. It's (not *exactly*, but *basically*) equivalent to writing this:

```
def root
  return nil if application == nil
  
  application.config.root
end
```

Comment: Don't forget about `application #=> false` in your last two definitions of `root`.

Comment: That's why I said "not *exactly*, but *basically*" -- yes, technically, ruby has two possible "falsey" values: `nil` and `false` - so the final method definition could really be more like: `return application if application == false || application == nil`. But I think it's reasonable to assume `application` is not going to be `false`. So I omitted that technical hypothetical possibility to keep the code sample simpler.

Answer (score 2):

### Avoiding NoMethodError

Ruby code can throw a NoMethodError when invoking methods on an expression that evaluates to nil, or on an object that doesn't #respond_to? a particular method. While newer versions of Ruby support the [safe navigation operator](https://rubyinrails.com/2017/11/17/safe-navigation-operator-ampersand-dot-in-ruby/) to guard against invoking methods on instances of NilClass, older code often needs this type of construct to avoid raising exceptions.

In peudocode:

```
define method "root":
  if application does not evaluate to nil, then
    invoke method config on application, then
      invoke method root on application.config
```

In Ruby >= 2.3, you could potentially rewrite this method as:

```
def root
  application&.config.root
end
```

However, there are cases where `&.` isn't fully equivalent to `obj && obj.method`. The former just protects against calling methods on nil. For example, if `application.nil?` and `application.respond_to? :config` are both false, using the safe navigator when calling `application&.config` will still raise an exception.

Whether the logical AND in your example is necessary because of how the *application* variable is set or used, just a legacy idiom, or kept for backwards compatibility with earlier versions of Ruby is something you'd have to investigate in the Rails code base. In any case, **the logical AND in your example guards against NoMethodError exceptions.**

Answer (score 2):

According to widely-used ruby style guides, https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#if-as-a-modifier, need to prefer modifier `if/unless` usage when you have a single-line body. Another good alternative is the usage of control flow `&&/||` (i.e. what you're asking about).

```rb
# bad
if some_condition
  do_something
end

# good
do_something if some_condition

# another good option
some_condition && do_something
```